# How to remove permanent speed items effects?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

In creative I got a speed item and the effects (like 100 blocks per second) will not go away, it won't go away and its super annoying and no one will help me. I have tried milk, log in log out, kill myself, and shut down my computer.

Comment: Milk should remove all potion effects, are you sure you've tried that?

Comment: if you read the whole thing i said milk soes not work

Comment: If that isn't solving the problem, reinstall the game.

Comment: its a server that wont work and i tried it

Comment: If it's a server, then a moderator could quite possibly be messing with you. A command block could be set up to give you the effect, or even a beacon.

Comment: NOPE DOESN'T WORK

Comment: Is it just that server, or are your other worlds bad too

Comment: no ones messing with me someone dropped something enchanted on me and i cant stop speading

Comment: Throwing the item away should work. Give us more details on the item, for example does it show any attribute modifiers (like "+100% Speed")?

Answer (score 1):

Try typing:

```
 /effect @p clear
```

It will clear all the status effects that you currently have.
If it doesn't help, make sure that you don't have a repeating command block anywhere in your world that gives you a speed effect every tick.

But if you mean that you have an item in your inventory that gives you a speed effect when you hold it, then you should just get rid of that item.